# How can I pin first two top most widget in DraggableScrollableSheet widget?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, flutter-layout, mobile-development

I wanted to make my first two widget to pin in my DraggableScrollableSheet widget.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Scaffold
use body : column,

the column must have 2 children
first a container has your pin widgets
second Expanded and it's child is ListView or in your case DraggableScrollableSheet

Try this out may works.

Comment: I wanted to DraggableScrollableSheet  on the top of the page like google map has but i wanted to pin my first two widgets which is not possible what i mean by that is, i want to implement DraggableScrollableSheet on top but when i scroll inside my DraggableScrollableSheet and also i want to know if there is way we can use to put different widgets inside DraggableScrollableSheet.